# How do I use the same navbar if I have two different templates? base_generic & blog_generic

Tags: django, django-templates

One template separates the site content into two columns.

Another template does not.

The template that only has one column will be used for homepage (when not signed in), and settings page. The template with two columns (content main & content sidebar) will be used for everything else.

I tried adding:

```
{% include "base_navbar.html" %}
```

that only contained my nav tags, but nothing happened.

Comment: So you need to use the base_navbar.html in both the templates.

Answer (score 1):

Use extends instead of include

```
{% extends "base_navbar.html" %}
```